# ¿Cómo obtener valores de elementos creados dinámicamente en el DOM?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Tengo entendido que cuando se crea un elemento nuevo en el DOM con jquery ya no se puede acceder a el normalmente como $('.algunaclase'), el detalle es que no se como acceder a el.
Estoy haciendo una especie de blog en el que se puede comentar, los comentarios los añado con jquery y todo bien, pero al final de agregarlos al DOM quiero saber cuantos hay pero siempre me dice que hay 0.

```
$('.btncoment').on('click', function(){
    public_actual = $(this).data('id');
    $.ajax({
        type:'GET',
        url:'controllers/modelo_coment.php',
        data:'accion=obtener-coment&&id_public='+public_actual,
        dataType: 'json',
        success:function(respuesta){
            let resp = respuesta;
            if(resp[0].respuesta === "sincomen"){
                $('.modal-body').empty();
                let comment = $(`
                        <div class="sincomentario">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <p><span>No hay comentarios aun</span></p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    `);
                $('.modal-body').append(comment);
            }
            else{
                $('.modal-body').empty();
                for(data of resp){
                    let comment = $(`
                        <div class="comentario">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-1">
                                    <img src="assets/images/users/profile-pic.jpg" alt="user" class="rounded-circle" width="30" height="30">
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-11">
                                    <p><span>`+data.nombre_usuario+`</span></p>
                                    <p>`+data.contenido+`</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    `);
                    $('.modal-body').append(comment);
                }
            }
            
        },
        error:function(respuesta){
            console.log(respuesta);
        }   
    });
    $('.modal-title').text('Comentarios ('+ $('.comentario').length +')');
});
```

Este es el codigo que agrega los comentarios al DOM correctamente, pero al final a la hora de querer obtener los div con clase comentario me da 0, cuando en realidad hay mas.
Alguna ayuda?

Comment: ¿En qué parte exactamente intentas contar los elementos y qué criterio estás siguiendo para ello?

Comment: Justo antes de que termine esta función que estoy anexando lo que hago es modificar el texto que tenia un elemento por uno nuevo con el resultado de los elementos que hay.
$('.modal-title').text('Comentarios ('+ $('.comentario').length +')');

Comment: @FranciscoFreyre simplemente move/copia esa línea dentro de la función `success`, justo después de cerrar el `else` (_recién ahí es cuando los elementos son agregados al DOM_)

Comment: **Muchas gracias amigo, en verdad me ayudaste de mucho** @Marcos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

para encontrar lo que dinámicamente agregaste con la clase: `.comentario`
puedes hacer una búsqueda rápida en el `DOM` utilizando el interface `document`.

```
let targets = $(document).find(".comentario");
console.log(targets.length);
$(".modal-title").text('Comentarios ('+ targets.length +')');
```

Ejemplo de un output en consola:
en este caso era un archivo html al que se le agregaron 52 botones mediante ajax XD.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Documentación:**

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document

**Observaciones:**

Debes incluir esto dentro del `response` de `ajax`; si colocas esto fuera del `ajax` es posible que se ejecute antes de que el `ajax` termine su parte, te recomendarías que estudies `promesas`.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/35135488/4717133